# Get attribute of viewcontroller created with storyboard

Tags: ios, swift3, viewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

I'm currently learning swift and I'm trying to learn of instanciation from storyboard works, but the error I'm facing now isn't documented very much.

I created a viewcontroller in my main storyboard and I specified it's type as a custom class I called previously ***SimpleNewsViewController***, here's the code of my class, it is'nt complicated:

```
class SimpleNewsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UITextView!

var event: Events!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

On my main storyboard here is the custom ViewController I specified :
[My Storyboard implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAPm8.png)

Now here's the problem : In my code I instanciate my ViewController thanks to the instanciateViewController(identifier: "NewsView") and then I try to set my 3 attributes like in this piece of code :

```
...
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsView") as! SimpleNewsViewController
    //controller.myImage.image = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
    //controller.myText.text = "this is an example that can be really long"
    //controller.myTitle.text = "this is a title example
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
...
```

If I un-comment the three lines I have an error saying:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

The IDE also displays the error code and the thread (if that can help):
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xqMw.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right after instantiating the controller the outlets are not connected yet, you have to declare temporary variables and set the outlet properties in `viewDidLoad()`

```
...
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NewsView") as! SimpleNewsViewController
    controller.tempImage = UIImage(named: "image.jpg")
    controller.tempLabel = "this is an example that can be really long"
    controller.tempText = "this is a title example
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
...
```

---

```
class SimpleNewsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var myImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myText: UITextView!

var tempImage : UIImage?
var tempLabel = ""
var tempText = ""

var event: Events!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myImage.image = tempImage
    myLabel.text = tempLabel
    tempText.text = tempText
}
```