# Calling function from child view controller not working

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

Hi I have a parent view controller with a `mapView` and a child view controller within it, as a small container view on the bottom, and that container view is normally hidden. When I tap on a marker on the `mapView` from the parent view controller, I want to show that container view and change the labels on the child view controller to values I get from a database.

Right now, what I have here is me calling the function from the parent view controller (when the marker is tapped) to change the labels on the child view controller.

in my parent view controller:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
        
        
        
        AddressViewController.ID.selectedID = marker.snippet ?? ""
        
        
        UIView.transition(with: AddressView, duration: 1, options: .transitionFlipFromBottom, animations: {self.AddressView.isHidden = false}, completion: nil)
    
        let AddressViewController = AddressViewController()
        AddressViewController.loadAddressView()
        
        
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: marker.position, zoom: 16)
        mapView.animate(to: camera)

        return true
    }
```

in AddressViewController (the child view controller)

```
func loadAddressView() {
        
        if ID.selectedID == "" {
            print("ID did not pass")
            return
        }
        else {
            print("function worked")
            
            ref = Database.database().reference().child("Items").child(ID.selectedID)
            ref?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
                
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary  
            
                self.ItemNameLabel.text = value?["ItemName"] as? String ?? ""
                self.addressLabel.text = value?["AddressDisplay"] as? String ?? ""

            })
            
        }
    }
```

What is happening is that when I run it and press the marker, it crashes, and it tells me that `ItemNameLabel` is "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value." However, I could tell the function still was called because "function worked" (above) was still printed, only the label was found nil. So I tried things such as using a delegate and protocol to call the function, which, while it didn't crash, the delegate was never called for some reason (I might of been doing it wrong- if that is how to solve to problem, I would love it if someone please explain how to do it in my case). I also tried setting my label to the database data in the viewDidLoad of the child view controller, and calling the child view controller's loadView() from the parent view controller, and that didn't crash, but didn't change the label either.

Anyone have an idea on how to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `AddressViewController()` is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the **real** reference by segue or instantiation.

Comment: @vadian I actually did try instantiation but I got the same error with my label.

Comment: Right after instantiation the label is not connected yet. You have to use a temporary variable and set the label in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @vadian Could you give an example of this?

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445895/get-attribute-of-viewcontroller-created-with-storyboard/44446009#44446009

Comment: I did this, and my labels changed, but they changed to "", which is what I initialized them to, instead of the what I want them to be. I called `viewDidLoad` within my marker `didTap` function. Is that the right method to call? what I need is to get the AddressVC to reload its view, not be presented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initiating a view controller as if it was a regular model class. This will initiate the view controller, but you do not instantiate the view controller to appear in your storyboard. For this reason your view life cycle is not used and the item label will not be initiated and is therefore nil.

I will assume that the container view is the only child of your prent view controller. If this is richt, you should instantiate your AddressViewController in your viewDidLoad like this:

```
let addressViewController = self.childViewControllers.first as! AddressViewController
```

I assume the Child View Controller is there and can make an explicit unwrapping.

Since you need to hide your container view, you can create an outlet to the parent viewcontroller and when the user clicks on the marker you unhide the container and call the loadAddressView like this:

addressViewController.loadAddressView

Since your AddressViewController is initiated properly all the labels are initialized and will work.

Kind regards,
MacUserT

Comment: This works but it shows my container view as a whole screen, and I only want to show my container view as a child view controller, or in other words, just as a small box in the middle of my screen.  Is there any way I could do that? I have it set up as a container view on my parent view controller right now.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Hang on, will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! it worked! the only minor thing is that `childViewControllers` has been deprecated and changed to `children`.